# How to create a submenu inside a dropdown menu in flutter that opens side to the menu item?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, submenu

[image]

there is a dropdown menu with list of items when a user click on dropdown item another sub menu need to be open to side of the menu item. to display other menu options.

expecting dropdown menu contains submenu items in flutter.

Comment: Flutter 3.10 added some cascading menu stuff.  Check it out in the release notes.

Comment: if you are planing to build desktop app, you can check fluent_ui

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a rabbit hole to learn how to use, but you'll probably have to dive into the [Overlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) class. Here's a good article explaining what it does and how to use it: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/implemented-overlay-in-flutter-fe60d2b33a04

Overlays are generally used for overlaying things on top of other widgets, like popup modals, dialogs, floating buttons, etc, in a way where the position isn't constricted to where it is in the widget tree.